# Webpack 2 livereload not working when moving input and output definiction from package.json to webpack.config.js

Tags: configuration, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, livereload

This is little bit strange. I know that webpack can be very picky about its configuration setup, but this is a very basic example:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpactest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && webpack -d --watch",
    "build:prod": "rm -rf ./dist && webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

if I change the package.json "server" key to:

```
"server": "webpack-dev-server --entry ./src/app.js --output-filename ./dist/bundle.js",
```

Live reload will work again.

I defined the "entry" and the "output" keys in webpack.config.js, so I suppose it should work... But "on file edit", no reload is triggered. What is wrong with my webpack.config.js configuration?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app.js"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/sass/main.sass")
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/sass")
        ],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                options: { sourceMap: true }
              }
            }, 
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        // second rule
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## - FIXED -

This video helped me to fix it: 
[THE WEBPACK CORE CONCEPTS | Webpack 2 Basics Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DDVr6wjJzQ)

I removed the empty object

```
  {
    // second rule
  }
```

I moved the `output` key on the end of webpack.config.js.
In `output` I added `publicPath` (so that the server knows where to watch for other files). I also removed the slash (`/`) after `dist` in the `path` key.

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist' 
  }
```

Now, live reload is working and my config file looks like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app.js"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/sass/main.sass")
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/sass")
        ],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                options: { sourceMap: true }
              }
            }, 
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        })
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist' 
  }
}
```